Update second combobox when parameter is passed into first combobox from app1
I have an app (app1) that I'm passing parameters to a second app (app2). In app2 I have a Name combo box and a Manager combo box. When the app2 is used by itself, when a name is selected from the name cb the manager cb selects the manager for that user. If app1 is used first and the parameter is passed to app2, the correct name is displayed in the cb but the manager cb doesn't update until you select a different name or clear it and select the same name. How can I get the manager cb to update when the parameter is passed into the name cb from app1?
App1:
EditForm1: Onsuccess:
If(
    IsBlank(ComboBox2.Selected.DisplayName),
    Navigate(
        Screen1,
        ScreenTransition.None
    ),
    Launch("https://apps.powerapps.com...",{varADName:ComboBox2.Selected.DisplayName, varTermDate:DataCardValue14.SelectedDate})
)

App2
cbName: DefaultSelectedItems: If(IsBlank(Param("varADName")),Blank(), {Value: Param("varADName")})
cbManger: DefaultSelectedItems: IfError( Office365Users.Manager(ComboBox1.Selected.Mail),Blank())
